# Google Cloud SCTP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to test SCTP traffic from the internet to instances within GCP but this is not working, checking through firewall documentation, is it safe to conclude that GCP does not allow SCTP traffic from the internet to instances?

[image]

If this is true, what is the rationale behind this? SCTP is a major protocol that is used in telecom.

Comment: In Google Cloud you will need to use protocol forwarding to support SCTP  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding or tunnel over UDP.

Answer (score 1):

Google blocks all traffic going in and out of VM instances to the Internet. This is done most probably for security reasons maybe realiablity and ease of managing such a vast infrastructure as Google has.

The image you posted ([from GCP firewall documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic)) says, that direct use of SCTP outside GCP network is blocked. For the moment you can go to the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and create a feature request for this functionality.

As a workaraound you can always try to tunnel it inside other protocols (like @John Hanley suggested) or use VPN. Nothing else comes to mind.